# Packet Sniffer under Linux in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, raw-sockets

I try to capture network pakets with a raw socket under linux..
This sometimes works. It seems that I can capture some of the conversations, but not all.

I create a socket:

```
sock = socket( PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

then I bind it to eth0 by:

```
struct sockaddr_ll sll;
struct ifreq ifr;

memset( &sll, 0, sizeof( sll));
memset( &ifr, 0, sizeof( ifr));

strcpy( ifr.ifr_name, "eth0");

if(( ioctl( sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr))==-1)
{
   printf( "error\n");
   return(-1);
}
sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
sll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
sll.sll_protocol = htons( ETH_P_ALL);

bind( sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sll, sizeof( sll));
```

then I try to receive:

```
int packetsize = 65535;
char packet[packetsize];

struct ether_header *eth = (struct ether_header *) packet;
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) (packet + sizeof(struct ether_header));

struct tcphdr *tcp = (struct tcphdr*) (packet+sizeof( struct ether_header)+sizeof( struct iphdr));
struct udphdr *udp = (struct udphdr*) (packet+sizeof( struct ether_header)+sizeof( struct iphdr));



int k;

while(1)
{
    k = read( sock, packet, sizeof( packet));

    if( k>0)
    {
        if( ntohs( eth-> ether_type) == 0x0800)
        {       
            inet_ntop( AF_INET, &ip->saddr, source, 16);
            inet_ntop( AF_INET, &ip->daddr, dest, 16);

            switch (ip->protocol)
            {
            case 6://TCP
                printf( "TCP: %s:%d -> %s:%d\n", source, ntohs( tcp->source), dest, ntohs( tcp->dest));
                break;
            case 17://UDP
                printf( "UDP: %s:%d -> %s:%d\n", source, ntohs( udp->source), dest, ntohs( udp->dest));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }//switch           
        }// if 0x800    
    }//if( k>0)
}//while
```

I can capture some of the packets in the network, but not all.
It seems that I miss whole conversations between two parties.

Does anybody have an idea, what I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Dirk

Comment: Run `tcpdump` in parallel and check which packets exactly you are missing. Without this information it is unlikely that anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: ... or easier as `tcpdump` run wireshark aside.

Comment: if you are listening on a socket, you aren't going to get any packets not sent to that socket. It sounds like you want to sniff all network traffic.

Comment: `tcpdump(1)` is built around a library that does packet capture. Why not use that instead of (re)inventing a square wheel?

Comment: I've already tried to run tcpdump in parallel.  
due to the big amount of packets it's really difficult to compare the outputs of both programs.

tcpdump uses libpcap, which creates the socket the same way, I do.

Is there a difference which receive/read function I use?

What is the exact difference between:
read() and

Comment: I've already tried to run tcpdump in parallel.  
due to the big amount of packets it's really difficult to compare the outputs of both programs.

tcpdump uses libpcap, which creates the socket the same way, I do.

Is there a difference which receive/read function I use?

What is the exact difference between:
read() and
     recvfrom(sock, packet, ETH_FRAME_LEN, 0, NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 5):

Unless this is some sort of homework exercise or an exercise in masochism, I strongly suggest you use `libpcap` which which will provide a portable way of solving this problem that has been tested to death. `libpcap` is what `tcpdump` and `wireshark` use under the hood.

Comment: libpcap can deal with a lot of special cases: ethernet, WLAN,
old versions of Linux, OSX, Windows. I just need one special scenario

Comment: I've tried doing this through my own socket implementation, and after hours of debugging gave up and got `libpcap` working in half an hour. YMMV on 'can't be this complicated'.

Comment: @Dirk It's somewhat complicated. That's why libpcap is a better choice, it has a much easier API, with more features. However, 1. You need to set the network card in promiscuous mode, otherswise you only see frames with your own MAC address 2. On a switched ethernet, you will not see all packets in the network - you need to set up a mirror port on the ethernet switch to do that. 3. Verify that the packets you want to receive really are encapsulated directly over ethernet, and not e.g. in vlan frames/GRE tunnels. Your code also miss out(or parse incorrectly) on IPv6 packets and non-IP packets.

Answer (score 2):

If by "whole conversations between two parties" you mean hosts other than the one running your code, you need to set the interface into promiscuous mode.

Speaking of `libpcap`, a good place to see how to enable promiscuous mode, is [pcap-linux.c](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/pcap-linux.c) in the `libpcap` sources. Search for `IFF_PROMISC` (old kernels) and `PACKET_MR_PROMISC` (the new fancier/more complicated way).

Comment: Along with this, search for PACKET_RX_RING, this is *the* way to do this on linux. Though to TBH, `libpcap` will have an implementation of this.